# How to increase code coverage to 80 percentage in Jasmine test case

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, components, karma-jasmine

I have written completed writing HTML, TS and service for angular components. I now have started writing test cases..but I cannot reach 80 percentage. Can someone please help how to reach till 80 percentage. Also, is there some tool which can help me determine what cases I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

In the root of your application, there should be a `coverage` folder. Open the  `index.html` in this folder and it will show you which lines, statements, branches (if, else) and functions/methods are covered. Coverage means does your unit test traverse those areas.